# mysql time to php conversion different on different server

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone, datetime-format

I have an issue Regarding time Zone I am fetching data from mysql

and want to convert according to given time zone let say mysql data return time is

```
2014-05-20 16:32:52
```

and here is my code

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($driverPickUpTime); 
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Asia/Riyadh'));  
$temp = $dateTime->format(CNOC_DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
```

the issue is this code return different time on different server like on dev and live having same DB connection  there is 2 hours difference. i want same time on both server

Answer (score 1):

`new DateTime()` accepts a timezone as second parameter. By providing the timezone that is stored in the database you should always get the correct result:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($driverPickUpTime, new DateTimeZone( /*enter DB timezone here*/ ));
```

Comment: thanks Gerald i have already tried but not succeed unable to understand why it showing two different time fetching from same db

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get the time from mysql as UTC.. see mysql UTC_TIME and UTC_DATE [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-time) and then switch timezones using PHP